# Definition of a determinant Peskin&Schroeder

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, grassmann-numbers, ghosts, functional-determinants

In page 514 of Peskin&Schroeder we are given the definition of a determinant as
$$
\det\left(\frac{1}{g}\partial_\mu D^\mu\right)=\int{\cal{D}cD\bar{c}\exp\left[i\int {d^4x\bar{c}(-\partial^\mu D_\mu)c}\right]}\tag{16.31}
$$
and as the authors say this is the same definition as equation (9.69) where we have
$$

$$
\det(B)=\left(\prod_i\int{d\theta^*_id\theta_i}\right)e^{-\theta^*_i B_{ij}\theta_j}\tag{9.69}
$$
I do not see the resemblance. How can I show that these two equations use the same definition of the determinant?

Comment: $\theta_i \to c(x)$, $\theta_i^* \to {\bar c}(x)$, $B_{ij} \to \delta^4(x-y) \partial^\mu D_\mu$ and $\sum_i \to \int d^4 x$. The factors of $i$ and $g$ are overall normalizations in the path integral which we do not care about.

Comment: These aren't _definitions_ of determinants. We can prove (9.69), then extend the logic as per @Prahar's comment to prove (16.31).